# How to play against friends in Medal of Honor?

Tags: ps3, psn, medal-of-honor

A friend and I both have Medal of Honor for the PS3. We want to play against each other in online multiplayer mode, but we don't know how. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: I don't know if the PS3 tag is necessary here. Someone with the game should retag if it's the same everywhere.

Comment: I am pretty sure most game intentionally prevent this so players can't 'boost' or 'rank up'

Comment: @TylerAndFriends, good point!

Answer (score 1):

Just connect to PSN (PlayStation Network). You can do this either wirelessly with newer models, or with an ethernet cable.

Once you've connected, create a PSN account. Then, insert the game disc.

Go to Multiplayer and scroll down to play with friends. You'll have to get your friend's user name and add it to your friends list. Then, select the friend there.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you, but doing by this way we always are dropped in the same team.

Comment: @manix can't you switch team in game?

Comment: @Novarg, I tried, but it did not work. My "solution" for now is send a friend invite to someone of  the other team, and then join your session. (but, it only works if the other person accept the invite rapidly)

Comment: @manix is there also an "after game lobby"? If so, do there exist parties/groups/whatever? It might be that you and your friend are in the same group, so you can't change team yourself while playing(talking about the parties as they were(or still are) in cod)